# When click "clear data", database is deleting. How can I solve this?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I don't want to delete database of application when click the "clear data" button. How can i solve my problem..

I searched but could not find anything.

Please help, thanks..

Edit: Hey ! I want to create a recipes application without internet connection. I created a sqlite that contain recipes. But user when click clear data, everything deleting.. Please help now..

Comment: If the user wants to get rid of your application or its data, he/she should be able to do so. What is the problem you're trying to solve by not deleting a database?

Comment: It's not a problem, it's a feature.

Comment: Edit: Hey ! I want to create a recipes application without internet connection. I created a sqlite that contain recipes. But user when click clear data, everthing deleting.. Please help now..

Comment: Remove (or hide, or disable) the "Clear data" Button.

Answer (score 5):

**That's obvious behavior of *clear data* feature, you cannot do anything with that.**

If you are not storing user entered data in `DataBase`, you can fetch original `DataBase` from your server whenever there is no `DataBase` available in your app.

Other option you can try is, keep your `DataBase` in sdcard also, but in this case also user can delete DataBase from sdcard

**Suggestion :** If its all about static data, you can use xml/json file, keep it in assets folder and fetch data from it.

Comment: Edit: Hey ! I want to create a recipes application without internet connection. I created a sqlite that contain recipes. But user when click clear data, everthing deleting.. Please help now..